# What are different parameter used for wxloader?

Tags: kognitio-wx2

Hi I am new to wx2 and not able to get proper documentation for it. 
I need to understand the what parameters we can pass to the wxloader utility?
i.e. what do `-b` and `-f` refer to in the command below?

```
wxloader -z Server_Ip -u User_name -p password -b /test/.test.err -f '|' --blank-null --trim-varchars -t "$TABLENAME"  /path_to_file
```

Also why we are using `'|'` after `-f`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Kognitio documentation (command line tools)

```
Usage: wxloader -s <dsn> -u <user> -t <table> <filename>
```

**Conversion options:**

```
-F, --field-format-file <file>    File containing field format string
-w, --wcb-file                    Load WCB file
-D, --date-format <fmt>           Format of dates [YYYY-MM-DD]
-S, --timestamp-format <fmt>      Format of timestamps [YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS]
-T, --time-format <fmt>           Format of times [HH:NN:SS]
    --implied-dp                  DECIMAL fields have implied decimal points
    --min-year <year>             Two-digit years are no earlier than <year>
    --null-value <str>            String to be translated to NULL
-N, --naive-delimiting            Quotes have no special meaning
-f, --field-separator <char>      Field separator character [,]
    --long-field-separator <str>  Field separator string
    --load-no-nulls               Use zero or blank for all blank fields
    --separator-terminated-values Expect a field separator after last field
    --pad-short-records           Use NULL for missing trailing fields
    --truncate-strings            Silently truncate overlong strings
    --trim-varchars               Remove trailing spaces from VARCHAR fields
    --preserve-leading-spaces     Don't trim leading spaces from fields
    --truncate-long-records       Ignore excess fields in a record
    --blank-null                  Blank strings are always NULL
    --exclude-fields 1,2,3,...    List of field numbers to exclude
    --currency-symbol <char>      Ignore this symbol before numeric fields
    --decimal-point <char>        Decimal point character if not '.'
    --thousand-separator <char>   Thousand separator character if not ','
    --quote <char>                Character to quote strings if not "
    --char-for-unknown <char>     Character to use for unimportable chars
    --int-allow-decimals          Round non-int values for int columns
```

If a format string is given with -F, it overrides all field conversion options.
Field conversion options are ignored if -w is given.

**Record-level conversion options:**

```
   --record-terminator <char>    Record terminator character [\n]
    --record-type <type>          Type of record, default auto
    Valid record types are:
        term    terminated by record terminator, no quoted strings
        qterm   terminated by record terminator, quotes surround strings
        fixed   fixed-width records, must specify --record-width
        auto    discern record type from format string/column types
    --record-width <width>         Size of fixed-width record in characters
```

**File-level conversion options:**

```
-c, --character-set <charset>     Character set of input file
    --file-start-offset <n>       Skip <n> bytes at start of file
    --skip-records <n>            Skip <n> records at start of file
    --max-records <n>             Load no more than <n> records
```

**Reporting options:**

```
-v, --verbose                     More commentary
-q, --quiet                       Less commentary
-b, --bad-records-file <file>     Destination for rejected records
    --log-file <file>             Output to file
    --max-conversion-errors <n>   Stop on more than <n> conversion errors
-P, --show-progress               Show progress indicator (default)
    --no-progress                 No progress indicator (default if -q)
    --progress-interval-records n Update progress count every <n> records
    --progress-interval-bytes n   Update progress count every <n> bytes
    --progress-interval-seconds n Update progress count every <n> seconds
    --show-timings                Show timing information
```

**Behavioural options:**

```
-t, --table <name>                Destination table [required]
-d, --truncate-table              Truncate table before import
    --no-statistics               Don't update table statistics after import
    --use-checksums               Use checksums on data blocks
    --no-checksums                Don't use checksums (default)
```

In your case,

```
wxloader -z Server_Ip -u User_name -p password -b /test/.test.err -f '|' --blank-null --trim-varchars -t "$TABLENAME"  /path_to_file
```

You try to connect to the server abd exporting a table into pipe delimited file.

`-f` is for the field separator and `|` is nothing but the actual field separating string